# Rdlc conditional report

Tags: rdlc

I'm using RDLC in asp.net.

My report will fetch data from the table that has **BankId**, **Amount** and **Trans-Type** fields.

The report has only two columns, that is **BankId** and **Amount**.

I have grouped by the **BankId** column, but if the field has **Trans-Type** = *Bill* it should be exempt from the group **Amount**; if it has **Trans-Type** = *Payment* it should be included in Amount.

I used this...

```
=IIF(Fields!TransType.Value="Bill-PMT" , RunningValue(Fields!DrAmt.Value,sum,"Group1") , RunningValue(Fields!DrAmt.Value,sum,"Group1")-(Fields!DrAmt.Value) )
```

Like:

```
Bank1 25000
Bank2 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something I would solve on datasource - i.e. change query to something like

```
    select sum(NormalizedAmount) as Amount, BankID
    from (
      select 
        case when TransType = 'Payment' then DrAmt 
        when TransType = 'Bill' then -DrAmt else 0
        end as NormalizedAmount,
        BankID
      from Amounts  
    ) as subselect
    group by subselect.BankID
```

Answer (score 0):

For your **Amount** expression at the group level you can use something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TransType.Value <> "Bill-PMT", Fields!DrAmt.Value, 0))
```

i.e. **Amount** is always 0 for *Bill* types.

Unless you're specifically looking for a running total *RunningValue* shouldn't be required.